Isolate character in string in data frame to create new column based on it
I try to isolate year in cell column to create a column this value year, such as a column Period with 2071-2100 or 1971-1980 value and another one with ssp such as column named ssp with ssp585 value or NA if none, like here, in this ex data frame:
  cell                          value
1 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285045  -1.224624
2 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285046  -1.281082
3 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285047  -1.319440
4 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285048  -1.350405
5 Europe1971-1980_285049        -1.401907
6 Europe1971-1980_285097        -1.687694

df <- structure(list(cell = c("Europe2071-2100ssp585_285045", "Europe2071-2100ssp585_285046", 
"Europe2071-2100ssp585_285047", "Europe2071-2100ssp585_285048", 
"Europe1971-1980_285049", "Europe1971-1980_285097"
), value = c(-1.2246238440088, -1.28108157943565, -1.31944037758433, 
-1.35040529202929, -1.40190667269474, -1.68769410847146), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

To have something like:
  cell                          value     Time      ssp
1 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285045  -1.224624 2071-2100 ssp585
2 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285046  -1.281082 2071-2100 ssp585
3 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285047  -1.319440 2071-2100 ssp585
4 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285048  -1.350405 2071-2100 ssp585
5 Europe1971-1980_285049        -1.401907 1971-1980 NA
6 Europe1971-1980_285097        -1.687694 1971-1980 NA

Thanks for any suggestions,

We can use regex to capture the output that we want based on pattern in data.
In base R, we may use strcapture function.
cbind(df, strcapture("[a-zA-Z]+(\\d+-\\d+)(ssp\\d+)?.*", df$cell, 
                     proto = list(Period = character(), ssp = character())))

#                          cell     value    Period    ssp
#1 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285045 -1.224624 2071-2100 ssp585
#2 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285046 -1.281082 2071-2100 ssp585
#3 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285047 -1.319440 2071-2100 ssp585
#4 Europe2071-2100ssp585_285048 -1.350405 2071-2100 ssp585
#5       Europe1971-1980_285049 -1.401907 1971-1980       
#6       Europe1971-1980_285097 -1.687694 1971-1980       

There are two capture groups in the regex. First (\\d+-\\d+) extracts the one (or more digits) separated by - followed by another set of one (or more digits).
The second extracts ssp followed by one (or more digits) (ssp\\d+). However, we have marked this capture group as optional (using ?) since not every cell has the ssp value.

And same regex can also be used in tidyr::extract
tidyr::extract(df, cell, c("Period", "ssp"), '[a-zA-Z]+(\\d+-\\d+)(ssp\\d+)?.*')

However, note that tidyr::extract has been superseded with separate_wider_regex.

Thank you for your answer, it working well, however I've slightly modified my question, maybe you can modify your reply to answer it?

@TristanU Updated the answer accordingly.

You could probably use the substr() function to accomplish this. If the  characters in front of your period and in between the ssp do not change, this might be an easy way.
substr(x, start, stop)

